# JSON cannot ready property of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I am calling API that is returning JSON array I am iterating over this array and map each value to new object and then push it new array.

Issue is when value from API is `null` i get

```
Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

but in my code i am handling `null` but still getting this error....

```
let comArr = [];
    JSONData.issues.forEach(element => {
      comArr.push({   
        Resolution: (element.fields.resolution.name === null) ? "some default value" : element.fields.resolution.name,

      });
    });
```

Comment: From the error and the code you have supplied, It seems that `resolution` is `null` and not `name` itself.

Comment: sorry when i log `element.fields.resolution.name` is null

Comment: Try doing `(element.fields.resolution === null || element.fields.resolution.name === null)`

Comment: You should check each part for failure, element then element.fields, then element.fields.resolution and then finally element.fields.relolution.name, also in JavaScript null has no meaning, check for undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that `element.fields.resolution` is `null` in same cases. Add a second if check on your statement, like:

```
if (element.fields.resolution === null){
 comArr.push({  Resolution: "some default value" });
}
else{
 comArr.push(Resolution: (element.fields.resolution.name === null) ? "some default value" : element.fields.resolution.name);
}
```

Comment: hey that was the issue i will accept answer, can you also tell me how to more elegantly handle that exceptions as i have over 30 values?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `resolution` object is `null` in some cases, so you should make a check to see if the object exists first. A cleaner solution would be to use `map`, since you are *always* pushing an object, rather than using `forEach`:

```js
const JSONData = {
  issues: [
    {
      fields: {}
    },
    {
      fields: {
        resolution: {
          name: 'foo'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      fields: {}
    },
    {
      fields: {
        resolution: {
          name: 'bar'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

const output = JSONData.issues.map(({fields: {resolution}}) => ({
      Resolution: resolution && resolution.name ? resolution.name : "some default value"
    }))
    
console.log(output)
```

Comment: hey, thanks but, looks like not working as expected as error as before:(

Comment: @Exc I've added a runnable snippet. The issue was that I put the ternary statements the wrong way around, my bad.